# My Cronjob dont work!

Tags: cron

i've added a cronjob with   `crontab -e`    and then i've added:    `*/10 * * * * sh /home/ftb/backup.sh`

in my backup.sh is:

`rm -rf backup/world
cp -r ftb/world backup/`

My backup.sh works if i execute it via    `./backup.sh`    its chmod 777

I want to execute every 10 minutes my backup.sh script in /home/ftb/backup.sh!!

Comment: Also, a good part for this would be to make sure you put a carriage return at the end of the line (if it is the only line or the last line in the crontab) or cron still looks for text because it doesn't know that is the end of the line.

Comment: Please don't make scripts world writeable with `chmod 777` because everybody (e.g. guest account) could change the script and so run commands with your user account. Rather use `chmod 755` to give group and other only read and execute permissions.

Comment: If the script is executable and its first line is a shbang line ( `#!/bin/sh` ) then you don't need to call `sh` explicitly in the crontab.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to give full paths in the script not just relative ones

backup/world should be something like /home/ftb/backup/world (or whathever the full path to that folder is).

The same thing goes for the second line.

Comment: is my cronjob/crontab correct and will work correctly?

Comment: You can also add the full path to sh so it becomes something like */10 * * * * /bin/sh /home/ftb/backup.sh

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use bash instead of sh. These are different and usually it's better to use bash in cron jobs.
Bash is a superset of sh, meaning everything you can do in sh you can also do in bash and bash has more features than sh.
In Ubuntu sh symlinks to dash, not to bash.
Furthermore you can execute this cronjob as root to be sure that the permissions are right.